# Android reducing height of an image leaves trail

Tags: android, android-imageview, image-scaling

I'm trying to set the height of an image view using single touch for my app. I want it to decrease image height as I swipe up and increase as I swipe down. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MainActivity";
    private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker = null;
    LinearLayout gameBoardView;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        gameBoardView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameBoard);
        initCardFromTop();
    }

    private void initCardFromTop() {
        Log.e("MainActivity: initCardFromTop()", "called");
        final ImageView ivTopCard = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        ivTopCard.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ivTopCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_arrow);
        ivTopCard.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.emerald));
//        ivTopCard.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
//        ivTopCard.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
//        ivTopCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.up_arrow);
        ivTopCard.setOnTouchListener(new ImageTouchListener());
        gameBoardView.addView(ivTopCard);
    }

    private void setHeight(ImageView ivCard, int height) {
        height = (height < 0) ? 0 : height;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = ivCard.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = height;
        ivCard.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    private class ImageTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            int index = event.getActionIndex();
            int action = event.getActionMasked();
            int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);

            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                        // Retrieve a new VelocityTracker object to watch the velocity of a motion.
                        mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                    } else {
                        // Reset the velocity tracker back to its initial state.
                        mVelocityTracker.clear();
                    }
                    // Add a user's movement to the tracker.
                    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                    // When you want to determine the velocity, call
                    // computeCurrentVelocity(). Then call getXVelocity()
                    // and getYVelocity() to retrieve the velocity for each pointer ID.
                    mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(100);
                    float deltaHeight = VelocityTrackerCompat.getYVelocity(mVelocityTracker,
                            pointerId);
                    setHeight((ImageView) view, (int) (view.getHeight() + deltaHeight));
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    // Return a VelocityTracker object back to be re-used by others.
                    mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

It works absolutely fine when I swipe up and increase height but when I try to reduce the height then it leaves a long trail which I don't want. It looks like this:
[image]

Interesting thing is that it works fine when I remove the background color of image and only use source but I need the background and using another imageview to do the same isn't a good option IMO. I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something very basic here. Please help, I'm stuck for very long now.

Comment: try calling invalidate() function on imageview

Comment: Calling invalidate() doesn't work. Neither calling it in initCardFromTop() nor in setHeight().